# Adding with word numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to add numbers by using both the integer form, and the text form of the numbers. I've gotten the integer aspect down, but am getting an error when trying to print the text version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

question = raw_input("Do math with numbers or text? (n/t) ")
if question == "n":


    x = int(input("Enter a digit: "))
    y = raw_input("Enter a sign: ")
    z = int(input("Enter another digit: "))
    sum = x+z
    diff = x-z
    mult = x*z
    divi = x/z

    if y == "+":
            print(sum)
    if y == "-":
            print(diff)
    if y == "*":
            print(mult)
    if y == "/":
            print(divi)

if question == "t":

    def toNum(words, num={}):
      if not num:
            teens = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen","sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",]
            tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
            hund = ["hundred", "thousand"]

       num["and"] = (1, 0)
            for place, word in enumerate(teens): num[word] = (1, place)
            for place, word in enumerate(tens): num[word] = (1, place * 10)
            for place, word in enumerate(hund): num[word] = (10 ** (place * 3 or 2), 0)

            input = result = 0
            for word in words.split():
                    if word not in num:
                            raise Exception(word)

                    hund, increment = num[word]
                    input = input * hund + increment
                    if hund > 100:
                            result += input
                            input = 0

            return result + input

    x = toNum(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    y = toNum(raw_input("Enter a sign: "))
    z = toNum(raw_input("Enter another number: "))

    sum = x + z
    diff = x - z
    mult = x * z
    divi = x / z

    if y == "+":
            print(sum)
    if y == "-":
            print(diff)
    if y == "*":
            print(mult)
    if y == "/":
            print(divi)
```

Once I run, type "t", and put in my numbers and sign, it says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '(`

Not really sure how to do math with the word numbers, and get them to total out. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For one, you shouldn't be "toNum"ing the "Enter a sign: " result, right? It is a sign, not a number. Secondly, I wouldn't use "input" or "sum" as variable names as those are used in standard python.

Comment: You have an indentation error in the pasted version: `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` on line 32

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: (I fixed your indent problem to get it to run) Ah, since you put the function in the scope of the if statement, I think the "num" variable is getting its scope confused. If you change one line to `z = toNum(raw_input("Enter another number: "), {})` it works. It would also work I think if you moved everything after `input = result = 0` in the function out of the `if not num:` statement, since you want it to always run, right?

Comment: Robert, it runs after changing the line, but it doesn't print out the answer. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Didyou also stop doing a 'toNum' on the operator?

Comment: I mean: `y = raw_input("Enter a sign: ") # No 'toNum' here`

Comment: Don't use `input` at all; use `raw_input`, and pass the result to `int`. As is, passing the result of `input` to `int` is either redundant (if you enter something that evaluates to an integer) or an error (if what you enter cannot be treated as an integer).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the indentation in my copy and reproduced the problem.  You haven't properly tested your "toNum" routine; it returns **None** for both the operation (not a problem, since you don't use it) and the second number (I did "one" + "seven").

As best I can see, the basic problem is that **toNum** doesn't return *anything* in some cases -- this brings back a **None** value.

I suggest that you add a few print statements to trace the problem ... and progress gradually.